# How to return promise in ajax done callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I'm trying to use promises to delay a function:

```
load: function(){

   var d = $.Deferred();

   $.ajax(......).done(function(resp){
      if(resp.error)
        return d.reject();

      ....
      return rend(); 
   });

   return d.promise();

},
```

I know `$.ajax` already returns a promise, but here `render()` will also return a promise so I cannot just use the `$.ajax` promise because

```
load.then(function() {   .....  })
```

should run after rend() completes.

Do you know how could I "merge" the `rend()` promise with `d`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> here render() will also return a promise so I cannot just use the $.ajax promise because `load.then(function() {   .....  })` should run after rend() completes.

Yes you can! That's just the power of [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) over `done`: it [*chains* the actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), waiting for the result of the callback (`render()`) before resolving the returned promise.

Use

```
load: function(){
  return $.ajax(…).then(function(resp){
//                 ^^^^
    if(resp.error)
      return $.Deferred().reject(resp.error);

      …
      return render(); 
   }); // this will resolve with the result of your render() promise
       // (or be rejeced with the .error)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rend().then(function() { d.resolve(); }
```

Call `rend` and then use the success/failure of that promise to resolve/reject `d`.

Comment: Yes. You'd also need to use the failure for a rejection. [Or just don't do this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)